# Not able to configure Redis cache in MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, azure, redis

I am new to Azure Redis Cache. I have just configured Redis cache in Azure Portal. I have installed StackExchange.Redis in my project through nuget. Below is the code for connecting Redis

```
ConnectionMultiplexer connection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("server.redis.cache.windows.net,ssl=true,password=primary access key");

        IDatabase cache = connection.GetDatabase();
```

I am getting below error while connecting:

```
JIT Compiler encountered an internal limitation.

at StackExchange.Redis.ConfigurationOptions.OptionKeys.TryNormalize(String value)
at StackExchange.Redis.ConfigurationOptions.DoParse(String configuration, Boolean ignoreUnknown) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\3ae0647004edff78\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange\Redis\ConfigurationOptions.cs:line 501
at StackExchange.Redis.ConfigurationOptions.Parse(String configuration) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\3ae0647004edff78\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange\Redis\ConfigurationOptions.cs:line 279
at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.CreateMultiplexer(Object configuration) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\3ae0647004edff78\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange\Redis\ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 728
at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.<>c__DisplayClass24.<Connect>b__23() in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\3ae0647004edff78\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange\Redis\ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 745
at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ConnectImpl(Func`1 multiplexerFactory, TextWriter log) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\3ae0647004edff78\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange\Redis\ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 761
at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(String configuration, TextWriter log) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\3ae0647004edff78\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange\Redis\ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 745
at App.Web.Controllers.HomeController.Index() in g:\Users\Workspaces\AlphaProject\App.Web\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 42
at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.ActionInvocation.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod()
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult](IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
```

Please suggest me some solution to connect Redis server.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please isolate the issue by trying to connect to Redis Cache using a Console app and see if that works?
Also you can refer to this sample for using Redis Cache in MVC http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/06/05/mvc-movie-app-with-azure-redis-cache-in-15-minutes/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this might be helpful. I was for Long hitting a similar error saying

> "ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   configuration
>   StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.CreateMultiplexer(object
>   configuration) in ConnectionMultiplexer.cs, line 844"

I looked at my Startup.cs, and re-wrote the following line like this, and now it works:

```
services.AddDistributedRedisCache(option =>
            {
                option.Configuration = "pretzelcache.redis.cache.windows.net:6380,password=qD+cdEMf5SI+2Psi7zUXdGSwjKCZnhwLvb3tmi3i6O8=,ssl=True,abortConnect=False";
            });
```

Earlier, Option.Configuration was directly trying to read the connectionString from appsettings.json file and something wasn't properly wired up there.

Cheers.